# external power supply

Tags: power-supply, usb-power

Using Rpi4. Using camera and IR lighting.
Would like it to be powered by rechargeable batteries.
What are my options..
I have found 'holding cases' for AA batteries but only for Raspberry 3s.
I have used Lithium power banks in the past but they tend to lack charge and also I cannot find connectors between power bank and Rpi4.

Been looking for ages now.  Is there a solution to any of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If lithium power banks lack charge, it would help to know how long you need to operate for. Given the current you need (ideally measured with an ammeter, although you could take published currents for each of the parts of your system) and duration, multiply the time by the current to get a rough estimate of how much energy you need (in Ah).

For example if your system is taking 0.5A and you want it to last a day then you need 0.5 x 24 = 12Ah. (I'm not suggesting you need 0.5A, but I don't know how much current you do need)

My guess if lithium power packs is not enough is that you are looking for quite a lot of energy. One option would then be a 12V lead acid battery plus a 12V USB adaptor (readily available for car cigarette lighters or as bare PCBs). You could use a car battery (although they don't really like being discharged) or better one designed for deep cycle discharge (but they are probably more expensive).

An improved answer would be possible once the energy requirements are known.

Comment: Hi, the battery option you mentioned would not be very practical fir me. It needs to be a compact solution. I have no knowledge of electronics but could apply myself and try and get an answer back to you soon. As an inadequate guide the 10000mha power supply was enough for what I needed but if I can use something other than that then I would like to consider it. Would you know if there are connector leads between these power banks and raspberry pi4s? I can only find for rpi3s :( thanks for ur answer

Comment: You suggested that the lithium power bank wasn't enough,but the one you have is enough? The pi4 is USB-C - they are readily avaialble from Amazon, Ebay, probably even many shops that sell anything vaguely technical as many modern mobile phones use the connector (but it is different to Rpi3's)

Comment: Sorry i should have been more explicit. The power charger is enough for 1 day. i would prefer longer.  But if not then that will have to be my fallback.  Does the power charge go from usb to usb then?

Comment: @closers instead of just voting to close give me half teh chance to address ur concerns?

Comment: Yes USB out from powerbank (probably USB-A - the oldest shape, but obviously depends on your powerbank) and USB-C into the Pi just as you would with a mains supply.

Comment: Thanks.  I admit I have not got a clue what i am doing here :)   I would still have preferred to see if i could supply a battery like this shows: https://thepihut.com/products/10aa-holder but cannot see how to connect it to rpi4

Comment: See https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/running-a-raspberry-pi-zero-from-an-aa-battery-pack. But I would work out what energy capacity you'll get from AA cells - lithium batteries have better energy density so I would have thought a lithium pack would last longer. You can also get 26Ah lithium powerbanks now!

Comment: thanks.  never soldered in my life!  Was hoping for 'plug-in-power'.  i will take a look ...

Comment: sorry forgot to accept. usb power pack is the way to go. thanks